# GitHub Access private file by URL

Tags: github

I have one file in private repository in github.com. I generate a fine-grained token with access Read-only for:"Pull requests" and "Metadata(mandatory)".

I tried download file by serveral URLs using:

`https://myuser:token_generated@github.com/myuser/myrepository/file.txt`
give me a blank page with only message "Not Found"

`https://myuser:token_generated@github.com/myuser/myrepository/blob/file.txt`
`https://myuser:token_generated@github.com/myuser/myrepository/blob/main/file.txt`
Send me to a personal page github 404 message "This is not the web page you are looking for."

`https://myuser:token_generated@raw.githubusercontent.com/myuser/myrepository/main/file.txt`
give me a blank page with message "404:not Found"

How can i write correct URL to download, or i need to give more access to Token?

Thanks all in advance!!!